# prevent default sort event in google chart table

Tags: javascript, events, sorting, charts, google-visualization

Is it possible to prevent default sort event from being fired in a google chart table object? If we take the example from [code playground](https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#sort_event) how could this be tweaked so as to e.g. prevent sorting from happening when clicking on "age" header?

i.e. doing nothing to the table chart (My idea is to have default sorting in all headers except in one, where another clicking event (managed by an event listener in an external js would fire) would be fired but without firing the sort event (and thus without appearing the little sorting arrow))

For example, the following doesn't work (it still calls the default sort method):

```
function drawVisualization() {
var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table'));
table.draw(sortData, null);

var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
chart.draw(sortData, null);

google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'sort',
  function(event) {
    if(event.column != 1){
      sortData.sort([{column: event.column, desc: !event.ascending}]);
      chart.draw(sortData, null);
    }
  }
);
}
```

Thank you for any pointers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the Table's `sort` option to `event`.  This disables the default sorting and makes the chart throw a "sort" event when the headers are clicked.  If you want to track sorting properly, you need to redraw the chart with the `sortColumn` and `sortAscending` options set:

```
var options = {
    sort: 'event'
};
google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'sort', function(event) {
    if(event.column != 1) {
        options.sortColumn = event.column;
        options.sortAscending = event.ascending;
        sortData.sort([{column: event.column, desc: !event.ascending}]);
        table.draw(sortData, options);
    }
});
```

[edit - full code for function to use custom sorting for table, based on playground code]

```
function drawVisualization() {
    var options = {
        sort: 'event'
    };
    var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table'));
    table.draw(sortData, options);

    var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
    chart.draw(sortData, null);

    google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'sort', function(event) {
        if(event.column != 1) {
            options.sortColumn = event.column;
            options.sortAscending = event.ascending;
            sortData.sort([{column: event.column, desc: !event.ascending}]);
            table.draw(sortData, options);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried using your example in the code playground, but nothing changed.. i.e. when clicking on "age", chart is not updated (as expected) but sort is applied to the table...

Comment: Sorry, there's a typo in the code: `chart.draw` should be `table.draw` in order to update the table.  You also have to pass `options` in as the options when calling `table.draw` the first time.  I'll update my post with the full code.  Also, nothing should happen when you click the "Age" column, as that is column 1, which you specified you don't want to sort when it is clicked.

Comment: In case it is unclear to people `sortData` is a `DataTable`, if you want to use a `DataView` first call `.toDataTable()` to get the `DataTable` then do `.sort()` and pass that as the first argument in `table.draw()`.