# Sort String-Type Columns in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I was wondering how I can sort a column which has either digit or 'x' value (for not defined). With conventional sort, the result is not correct and 17 comes sooner than 7.

Example:

```
17   
7    
9    
X
```

Want to sort it like:

```
7    
9    
17   
X
```

PS.
I am using:

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable()
data.addRow[{v:'17'}, {v:'7'}, {v:'9'}, {v:'X'}]
```

I want to be able to sort it in the event listener.

Comment: try a select sort and place a condition to set X as the highest value

Comment: You may pass a comparator function to Array.sort() to fulfil your needs. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Syntax

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript : natural sort of alphanumerical strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802341/javascript-natural-sort-of-alphanumerical-strings)

Answer (score 5):

You can use `localeCompare` with the `{numeric:true}` option in a comparator function:

```js
let arr = ["17","7","9","X"];

function comparator(a,b) {
  return a.localeCompare(b, "en", {numeric:true});
}

console.log(
  arr.sort(comparator)
)
```

If your array is of this format

```
[{ v: '17' }, { v: 'X' }, { v: '7' }, { v: '9' }];
```

You have to adapt the comparator a bit:

```js
var arr = [{ v: '17' }, { v: 'X' }, { v: '7' }, { v: '9' }];

function comparator(a,b) {
  return a.v.localeCompare(b.v, "en", {numeric:true});
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(
  arr.sort(comparator)
))
```

Comment: To sort objects like `{v: "7"}`, replace `comparator(a, b)` by `comparator({v: a}, {v: b})`.

Comment: @Luca, Thanks. It is clear. Could you please also explain how I can use it in event listener? Currently, I am using answer of following stack overflow post for sort on even: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20166551/prevent-default-sort-event-in-google-chart-table

Comment: As long as you have a variable that has the array, you can just plug that function in there.

Comment: @Luca, I tried, but still could not make it work, because some how I need to add 'event' in your code. The original one that I am using is: data.sort([{column: event.column, desc: !event.ascending}]);. How can I change your code such that a and b refers to entries of even.column?

Answer (score 1):

You could sort with a check for `'X'` and move this value to the end of the array.

By taking [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) without callback, all items are sorted as strings.

The sorting takes place in two parts,

1. checking for `NaN` and taking the delta of the boolean results, which means,

   ```
    value   value  isNaN  isNaN
      a       b      a      b    delta  meaning
   ------  ------  -----  -----  -----  -------
     NaN     NaN    true   true    0   a === b
     NaN   number   true  false    1   a  >  b
   number    NaN   false   true   -1   a  <  b
   number  number  false  false    0   a === b
   ```
2. take the delta of the values

```js
var array = [{ v: '17' }, { v: 'X' }, { v: '7' }, { v: '9' }];

array.sort(({ v: a }, { v: b }) => isNaN(a) - isNaN(b) || a - b);

console.log(array);
```

Comment: It looks to me that the OP may be using string values, so you may have to change your example a bit

Comment: Thanks @Nina. Actually, it is like a event listener that needs to always sort it when the column is selected in html.

Comment: Can you please explain that comparator a bit more? It is hard to make sense of

Answer (score 1):

You want [localeCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare).

```
// by default, "2" > "10"
console.log("2".localeCompare("10")); // 1

// numeric using options:
console.log("2".localeCompare("10", undefined, {numeric: true})); // -1
```

You can use this in a sort function ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)):

```
["17", "7", "9", "X"].sort(function(a,b) {
  return a.localeCompare(b, undefined, {numeric: true})
})
// ["7", "9", "17", "X"]
```